# How to splice list of items in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
list1 = [{letter:'A'}, {letter:'B'}, ..., {letter:'Z'}]
```

I want to go through the list and add a key value of "special":"yes" to all values that are in this `list2: ['A', 'C','Z']`

The ultimate goal I want is the resulting list:

```
list1 = [{letter:'A'}, {letter:'C'}, {letter:'Z'}]
```

How can I do this?

I tried iterating through list1, checking to see if in list2, if not, then splice an element out of it, but it does not work since all the indices change. Is splice not what I want here? What should I do instead?

Comment: So where is `"yes"` in the resulting list?

Comment: Do you wish to modify the original `list1`? Or do you just want to create a new, filtered list with only the elements that match one of the entries in `list2`?

Comment: I want to modify original list1 so it contains only items in list2 (but with the added special key value.

Comment: Just to get it right, you want the array of list2 to be compared with the array of objects from list1. And if the value of property letter from list1 compares to the value from list2, a new list3 has to be created?

Answer (score 2):

You have two things to do here, so let's break them down:

- filter keys which are not in some another list
- add a key to the other keys

You have an array, so filtering is easy:

```
list1 = [{letter:'A'}, {letter:'B'}, ..., {letter:'Z'}]

filtered = list1.filter(function (el) {
    return  list2.indexOf(el.letter) !== -1;
});
```

Now we want to add other keys, `Array.prototype.map` to the rescue:

```
final = filtered.map(function (el) {
    el.special = 'yes';
    return el;
});
```

Array.map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Array.filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Hope that helps!